# Connect my old Spring project to Spring Roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I'm wondering that if is it possible to connect my Spring based project to Spring Roo.

OK I have a complete project with Spring that has three layers (Service, DAO, Entity), but now I want to get rid of my DAO and Entity layers and produces these layers with Spring Roo (for convenience, rapid production to create aforesaid layers) but I insist to save my service layer and I've just wanted to inject Spring ROO's DAO layer in my service layer, as you know the DAO based on aspectj and I want to save the structure.

is it possible to inject DAO into my service layer?
does any tool exist that produce Entity and DAO layer likes Spring Roo ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enable Roo in any Spring project by following the instructions at section "6.4. Reenabling Roo After A Removal" of the Roo "Reference Documentation" at http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/current/reference/html/removing.html#removing-reversal